# HTML/CSS that worked in chrome looks all mangled up in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, web-frontend

So I am trying to create this success modal box which looks absolutely fine in Google Chrome but completely breaks in Firefox. Can I please get some help with what I am doing wrong and how can I make my front end code cross-browser compatible.

```css
.close-button {
  float: right;
  top: -24px;
  right: -24px;
  color: black !important;
  margin-bottom: -2.5rem;
}

#checkMarkContainer {
  text-align: center;
}

#checkMarkIcon {
  font-size: 13.5rem;
  color: green;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: contents !important;
}

#successTxt {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.8rem;
}

#subHeading {
  text-align: center;
}

.linksContainer {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
}

.linkIcons {
  font-size: 5.5rem;
  color: #105b63;
  display: contents;
}

.linkBtn {
  float: right;
  background-color: #105b63;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.close-button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <button mat-icon-button class="close-button" [mat-dialog-close]="true">
    <mat-icon class="close-icon">close</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div id="checkMarkContainer">
        <mat-icon id="checkMarkIcon">check_circle_outline</mat-icon>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h1 id="successTxt">Success!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h2 id="subHeading"> What do you want to do next?</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mt-3 linksContainer">
    <!-- Link 1 - start -->
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
          <mat-icon class="linkIcons"> vpn_key</mat-icon>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg linkBtn" routerLink="/keywords" [mat-dialog-close]="true">Grow your
            list
            with keywords</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Link 1 - end -->

    <!-- Link 2 - start -->
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center" style="margin-bottom: 1.5rem;">
          <i class="fa fa-bullhorn fa-lg linkIcons"></i>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg linkBtn" routerLink="/campaigns" [mat-dialog-close]="true">Create a
            new
            Campaign</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Link 2 - end -->

    <!-- Link 3 - start -->
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center" style="margin-bottom: 1.5rem;">
          <i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-lg linkIcons"></i>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg linkBtn" routerLink="/reports-dashboard" [mat-dialog-close]="true">Monitor
            campaign in
            Dashboard</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Link 3 - end -->

  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot from chrome]

[image: Screenshot of how the same code renders in firefox]

Any help would be appreciated. I am still quite noob when it comes to cross browser compatibility.The first screenshot is from chrome and the second one is from firefox.

Chrome version : 100.0.4896.127
Firefox version : 99.0.1

Comment: Which google chrome and firefox versions are you using?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out I edited the question to include versions as well

Comment: According to canIuse website display:contents is suppose to be compatible with both browsers but it still doesnt act the same :\

Answer (score 0):

Are you keeping your browser versions up to date? If the versions are not up to date, there may be differences in how the browsers render the styles.

Comment: Yes they are up to date

Answer (score 0):

If you are having troubles with some certain property for an element you can go to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com) to see what browsers support that property and which don't support it.

Comment: I also tend to develop code in Firefox because it supports all the stuff that chrome and other major browsers support and should look/work the same way for other browsers.